# Dataweave function issue when called from Munit

Tags: mule

```
%output application/java
%function splitEachRow(row) row splitBy p('field.delimiter')
%function convertStringToLocateDateTime(date,format)  ( date as :localdatetime {format: format})
%var record =  splitEachRow(payload) 
%var actionDateTime=record[0]
---
{
    dateTimefn: convertStringToLocateDateTime(actionDateTime ,p('action.date.time.format')),
    dateTime: actionDateTime as :localdatetime {format: p('action.date.time.format')},
    Action_Type__c:record[1]
}


while calling a function created within Dataweave script  getting below exception.It happens when I run it as  Munit test, when I deploy it in Server it works fine.

ERROR 2017-01-30 14:30:03,924 [main] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : -1 (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException). Message payload is of type: String
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. -1 (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)
  com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ExecutionContext$InternalExecutionContext:69 (null)
2. -1 (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException). Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor:32 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ExecutionContext$InternalExecutionContext.getVariable(ExecutionContext.scala:69)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.variables.VariableReferenceNode.value(VariableReferenceNode.scala:24)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.wrappers.DelegateValue$class.valueType(DelegateValue.scala:12)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************

ERROR - The test vba-prod-data-integration-test-suiteTest finished with an Error.
-1 (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException). Message payload is of type: String
org.mule.api.MessagingException: -1 (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException). Message payload is of type: String
    at vba-prod-data-integration-test-suiteTest.dw:transform-message{doc:name=Transform Message}(vba-prod-data-integration-test-suite.xml:16)
    at vba-prod-data-integration-test-suiteTest.mule:set-payload{doc:name=Set Payload, value=01/12/2017 11:03:07 AM|"Atlanta VAMC records uploaded"|0|3176342462|"Rating"|"020NEW"|0|"0609122664"|"020"|"020"|"3020486138"|||4|349|2||1||1|0.931|Ready to Work|3492328660|1|1762475691|"176247569117-JAN-1231763424622"|"A244840216033" }(vba-prod-data-integration-test-suite.xml:15)
    at appleFlow.munit:test{initialState=started, description=MUnit Test, ignore=false, abstract=false, id=MunitTestFlow$$EnhancerByMUNIT$$904837f0{vba-prod-data-integration-test-suiteTest}}(vba-prod-data-integration-test-suite.xml:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ExecutionContext$InternalExecutionContext.getVariable(ExecutionContext.scala:69)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.variables.VariableReferenceNode.value(VariableReferenceNode.scala:24)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.wrappers.DelegateValue$class.valueType(DelegateValue.scala:12)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Due to the formatting of the question it is totally unclear what you are asking. You should learn how to format your question. When editing there is a "How to Edit" box right beneath the edit area. Please consult the hints there...

Answer (score 0):

How you are calling the Dataweave function from Munit?

Answer (score 0):

I just call my subflow where my dataweave exists from mule unit test case
example:

```
<munit:test name="endpoints-test-suiteTest" description="MUnit Test">
        <flow-ref name="call-my-dataweave" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
        </munit:test>
```